# Which definition of "atheism" is the proper usage?

Tags: meaning, differences

This seems to be a creeping problem in that two competing definitions are being used for the term "atheism" that aren't necessarily compatible with one another.

One the one hand we have what appears to be the classical definition of "atheism" which describes it as the solid position that there is no God by describing at as the "belief that there is/are no God(s)"

**Support**: [Stanford](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/atheism-agnosticism/)

On the other hand there are some selected groups (and many atheists that you ask on the internet will tell you) that the term is the "absence or lack of belief in God(s)."

**Support**: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atheism)

Which definition is the proper usage? Are these competing definitions untenable and contradictory or can they be inclusively used as the Wikipedia article suggests?

What are some of the implications of "lack of belief" definition? Under that definition would babies be atheists? What about animals? Could inanimate objects technically be described as "atheistic?"

Comment: Both meanings are in common use. *Ergo*, both are legitimate definitions for the term. One of them is more useful, and perhaps it is worth promoting that one in religio-political discourse, but until such a time as one definition is clearly dominant they are both "proper".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which is the word that means neither "believer" nor "atheist" but somewhere in between?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46713/which-is-the-word-that-means-neither-believer-nor-atheist-but-somewhere-in-b) Babies and animals are irrelevant to matters of *theism*, and even the word *atheist* is only meaningful in opposition to what I would call a declining world-view. To me it's almost as "loaded" as ***heathen***. Even *secular* seems unnecessary in my world-view.

Comment: Nope, that question is about apatheism and assumes a definition for "atheism." This question is looking for a set definition of atheism itself.

Comment: Most vociferous atheists I know will refuse to categorize themselves as either, stating "how can a *non-belief* in a god, or flying horses, define me?" Suffice it to say,*we* label people who do not believe in any god as atheists.

Comment: I'm surprised to see that anyone thinks there is a second, different meaning of the word. In my life, I've only heard of atheists being people who do not have any religious beliefs. They do not believe in any god or gods.

Comment: There is no such single thing as _atheism_; all things that may be called that -- either by individuals referring to themselves, or by others referring to them -- are different. People who describe themselves as atheists have each reached that state by different means and for different reasons; ask a few if you doubt this. On the other hand, people who are labelled as "atheists" by theistic people are simply those who offend the theists by not attending to their demands, and those vary considerably; theistic definitions of "atheism" are essentially politics, not language.

Comment: @Tristanr The two definitions given in the question are both different from yours, so you need to consider things more carefully before talking about "a second, different meaning". Somebody who doesn't have religious beliefs is "non-religious". There are religions that don't have gods so it's possible to be an atheist and still be religious.

Comment: This question is dangerously close to off-topic. We can discuss meanings of the word *atheist*, but discussing *atheism* is off-topic. You can take that to Philosophy or wherever, but it doesn't belong here.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Tristan's statement matches the version in the question from Wikipedia, and I agree with him.  The first one is more about a claim of knowledge than belief (which I've heard before as the difference between "gnostic atheism" (borderline nonsensical) and "agnostic atheism"), and is a corruption of its usual intended meaning.

Comment: @Izkata Tristan's statement doesn't match Wikipedia. Wikipedia says not believing in god(s); Tristan says not being religious. There are religions that don't have gods: a follower of such a religion is religious but is an atheist.

Comment: David Richerby, my point was that the word *atheist* is normally used to refer to people who do not believe in any religion and therefore, do not believe in any god or gods. They live without any religion or god at all.

Comment: The idea that certain people think there is no god at all, is something extra and not necessary for not believing in one, or a religion. I have known of many atheists who are just not convinced one way or the other.

Comment: I think I have a definitive answer for the exact title question: atheism *should* be defined as "a love of hugs".  Maybe theism *should* mean "a love of hugs" too, because wouldn't that just be lovely? It's not what people mean when they use either word, but I think it should be.

Comment: Here in the US, "atheist" is like "feminist" in the sense that people don't want to use these words to describe themselves, even if the description would be accurate. There is an impulse to find euphemisms for "atheism," because both religion in general and fundamentalist religion are so strong here (as compared with Europe, for example). Euphemization blurs the meanings of words -- that's it's purpose -- so it's not surprising that it's hard to find a consensus on this word's definition. Pew Research says that 12% of Americans say they're "nothing in particular," only 1.6% "atheist."

Comment: To voice the very real distinctions between her own position on the matter and both the first definition above "agnostic," my partner (a retired editor) uses "apathist." Several in our congregation find this term appealing for naming their own views.

Comment: I am reminded of when Bertrand Russell was registering as a conscientious objector in England in WWI.  The registrar asked him his religion and he replied "agnostic".  The registrar asked him to spell it and then said something like "That's an new one on me.  But I guess deep inside we all worship the same God, eh?"

Answer (score 28):

When this distinction is made, the usual terms are:

- *negative* or *weak atheism* — lack of belief in gods (or a particular god)
- *positive* or *strong atheism* — belief in the nonexistence of gods (or a particular god)

(See for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_and_positive_atheism), or "[An Introduction to Atheism](http://infidels.org/library/modern/mathew/intro.html)" at infidels.org.)

I have four observations to make about this issue:

1. This is a very recent distinction, at least in mainstream discourse.* On Google Books, I can't find any relevant citations for *weak/strong atheism/atheist* before 2000. The distinction is not mentioned in the [entry for "Atheism and Agnosticism" (2004) in the *Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy*](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/atheism-agnosticism/), for example.

   (* People were making the distinction in the Usenet group alt.atheism at least by the early 1990s — [see the FAQ from 1993 for example](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/alt.atheism.moderated/WXfhRmkCgc4/4GZkRmFOcKEJ) — but the OP's concern seems to relate to mainstream usage.)
2. The distinction between *not believe* and *believe not* is one that is not usually made in ordinary English. When someone says, "I don't believe in Santa Claus," they mean that they believe that there is no Santa Claus. Linguists describe this fact by writing "*believe* is a verb of *medium subordinate negative implicature*" (see [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/116669/2175) for an explanation). So insisting on a distinction between "believe there is no X" and "don't believe in X" runs contrary to ordinary use of English.
3. This distinction relies on the way that belief is sometimes modelled in epistemic logic (see the [*Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy*](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-epistemic/)). Here a predicate B(*x*, *y*) may be introduced, meaning "agent *x* believes proposition *y*". Then the logician can distinguish between ¬B(*x*, *y*) meaning "it is not the case that *x* believes that *y* is true" and B(*x*, ¬*y*) meaning "*x* believes that *y* is false".

   But is the predicate version of belief really a good model? It can be criticised on the grounds that it presumes certainty in the agent — B(*x*, *y*) can only be *true* or *false*, whereas in real life there seem to be degrees of certainty of belief. This criticism leads to [probabilistic epistemic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_logic), in which the sharp distinction between *weak* and *strong* versions of disbelief is replaced by a gradation of strengths of belief.
4. It's usual for words to have multiple closely related nuances, so there seems no barrier to continuing to use *atheist* without regard to this distinction, except perhaps in technical works on the philosophy of religion.

   The *OED*, for example, defines *atheist* as

   > One who denies or disbelieves the existence of a God.

   where *disbelieve* has the meanings:

   > (1) To reject the truth or reality of.
   >
   > (3) Not to believe in; to have no faith in.

   so the *OED*'s definition of *atheist* covers both the *weak* and *strong* versions.

Comment: Precisely the answer I was going to give, and then some (quite a bit more, actually)! Nicely done. (This from a psychologist with *strong* interest in studying religion. :)

Comment: An older term for weak atheism is _agnostic atheism_, dating back to at least the 19th century.

Comment: @MSalters: They are similar, I agree, but I'm not sure that the older term quite maps onto the current one. *Agnosticism* in Huxley's sense is more like a combination of *skepticism* and *empiricism*, and so somewhat orthogonal to the modern distinction between types of atheism.

Comment: In reference to your point 1, the distinction is older than your sources are leading you to believe.  I, for one, was using these terms at least as far back as 1995, and as I didn't invent them others must have been using them for longer.

Comment: @Jules: Sure, people were making this distinction on alt.atheism in the early 1990s. But can you find a book published before 2000 that does so?

Comment: Why is publication of a book more relevant to dating the terminology than any other use?

Comment: @Jules: an appearance of the distinction in books (or scholarly papers) would help date the emergence of the idea into mainstream discourse. I suspect the distinction originates with the alt.atheism Usenet group (and indeed the alt.atheism FAQ was where I first encountered it). But the OP's question rests on the observation that this is a widespread distinction and so it's the spread into the mainstream that I am hoping to date.

Comment: @Jules: I've revised the section on recency. Does that make more sense now?

Comment: Excellent answer. I guess point two flies in the face of my answer. Then point three flies in the face of the rebuttal I might have made. But that is the issue more often or not: that real life is difficult to describe and no set of words can accurately cover every case (a point I hinted on at the end in my answer).

Comment: So it's the difference between "I don't believe in X"(I don't think X can be of any use to me) and "I believe there is no X"(I think there is no existence of X).

Comment: @aditya: No: there's no sense of "use" here.

Comment: Overall I like your answer, but your point 2 flies in the face of what I call common sense about English usage. I'll grant that there's an imprecise, logically confused vernacular usage like you describe, but I don't think that makes it *correct*. An analogy would be the use of double-negatives as emphatic negatives rather than negation-of-negation.

Answer (score 18):

It appears the situation is just as you described: there are two competing definitions, so neither could be said to be 'correct' or 'incorrect' from language point of view, as both are used.

Atheists tend to be biased towards the latter, often choosing a finer scale - a non-absolute theist/atheist and gnostic/agnostic system. (Some choose to add 'strongly care / doesn't care' into the mix.) Theists, especially vehement opponents to atheism are prone to choose the former as it presents atheism as just another belief, a religion without a god. That definition conforms to "strongly caring, gnostic atheist" in the "sliding scale" system, a relatively small sub-group of a much larger and more varied atheist society.

In essence, in the gnostic/agnostic theist/atheist system, the first definition would describe what is known as "gnostic atheists", actually a fairly small sub-group of the atheist population; ones who don't follow the agnostic atheist idea: "there is no proof for existence of God, and so far science can explain everything without God, so it's logical to assume there is none and follow up on that assumption", but actually negate the idea claiming there isn't any God for sure.

Comment: But what about the implications of the "lack of belief" definition?

Comment: *Some* atheists prefer to use the latter. There are atheists whose position could be characterized as "call me when you've got a proper reason for me to care about the idea of god". Historically, some such people have called themselves apatheists or ignostics, but at least some call themselves atheists. Bertrand Russell (with his infamous teapot, which desipte its fanciful imagery puts forth a problem of epistemology which Russell would have taken seriously at least for his own private contemplation) is arguably an example, and he referred to himself variously as an agnostic or atheist.

Comment: @RestinginShade: Children before they learn of the idea of religion are the epitome of agnosticism: they simply don't know - not even hesitating between two options but ignorant of their existence. As such they sit squat in the middle of the atheist/theist axis: no belief nor disbelief.

Comment: This answer IMHO gets to the crux of the problem. Often in belief disputes (political or religious) the two sides argue over which word(s) to use to cover a given concept. In this case, the two sides are instead arguing over which of two meanings to give the same word.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap: I'd even say "most". There are some people rabidly atheistic who would consider these "apatheists/ignostics" (currently commonly known as agnostic atheists) "not true atheists" - but every group in the world has a fanatic minority, and so that minority's opinion shouldn't reflect on the group as a whole.

Comment: @SF.: In fact, there is a degree of distinction between ignostic/apatheistic and agnostic, which respectively are "don't even know/care what this god fuss is meant to be about", as opposed to caring but not committing to an answer. In any case, I do think that your categorical "Atheists prefer..." is incorrect, unless you are yourself a member of group who feel that subtler opinions belong to those who are no true Scots --- er, atheists.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap: The word "prefer" is not categorical - or at least I meant it as such. There are many currents within the atheist society, but hard belief in lack of god (as religious opponents tend to picture all atheists) is simply relatively infrequent. Simply put, the two definitions match two groups of atheists, of different size. Opponents tend to deny existence of the larger group and picture the situation as if the minority was the whole.

Comment: @SF - Ah, you of course refer to [The Church of the Apathetic Agnostic](http://www.apatheticagnostic.com/) (motto: "We don't know, and we don't care".)

Comment: @SF. I have to say the categorical "Theists prefer..." in this answer is an inaccurate generalisation; There are a *lot* of theists, and many of them do not adhere to the same beliefs regarding the best methods of combating atheists.

Comment: @user: Two comments above yours.

Comment: agnostic are people who don't believe in religion but accept the idea of a god, while atheist don't care about both religion and god because they think that religion is instrument of power and god is an easy way to explain things we don't understand.

Comment: @Kiwy: You way oversimplified things with atheists and went straight on wrong with agnostics: Agnostics admit they *don't know* if there is a god. They vary too, some being equivalent of atheists in all practical respects, some being believers undergoing a crisis of faith, some struggling with two conflicting beliefs, etc. Refusing religion is not agnosticism, it's non-practising. Refusing worship of god (mandated by religion) while believing in existence of such is antitheism.

Comment: @SF Given that your "prefer..." wording has been misinterpreted by multiple people as categorical, perhaps it would be beneficial to alter your phrasing to more clearly match your intended meaning?

Comment: @user867: Good idea. Better?

Comment: @SF. That should do nicely.

Answer (score 8):

Re-appropriating the term *atheism* is what is causing the issue. If we break the word down it is clear that the first definition is what should be intended when using the word *atheism*. The prefix *a* has long been used as a reversal, or negation, for the term that follows it. The suffix *ism* has long been used for any kind of belief or organized thought system. The actual term is derived from the Greek word for god.

Here's what we are left with:

- Theism is a belief in god.
- Atheism is a belief in *not* god.

The confusion leading to this re-appropriation is from misplacing the negation. If we were to say that *atheism* means *not a belief in god* (notice the misplacement of the reversal/negation) then we are not being true to the word's structure and implied definition. The *ism* suffix already implies what it is, a belief or school of thought, and placing the negation on that is contradictory. The *a* does not negate the *ism*; it negates the root, *theo*. It is akin to saying that it is not a belief or school of thought, but (and the following might be better on philosophy.se) that is the same as saying that atheism and theism are in fact not opposites and are therefore in a different class of terms, which can lead one to think that they are not mutually exclusive, however their regular use suggests otherwise.

Atheists who want to re-appropriate the term's meaning are insistent that what they hold to is not a *belief* (however they might likely accept *school of thought*), so to overcome the above contradiction they replace the negation with the word *lack*, leading us to the second definition that you provided.

There is already a word for that, however: *agnosticism*. *Agnosticism* (also a school of thought, but not necessarily a belief) is characterized by confessing uncertainty on the topic entirely. Essentially, saying one is agnostic is the same as saying that one is unsure on whether there is a god or not. They are unsure if belief in a god is warranted, therefore, there is a lack of belief.

If one would characterize his opinion on the topic as *certainty that there is no god* (notice the negation placement) then one should rightly call oneself *atheist*. If one would characterize his opinion on the topic as *not having a belief or opinion* (notice the negation again) or *a lack of belief or opinion* then one should rightly call oneself *agnostic*.

---

Now this is a sensitive topic for some people. Trying to place what you believe into a single word is difficult at best and laying down the three terms, theism, atheism, and agnosticism, and demanding that all persons fit neatly into only one of them is not fair to them and does a great disservice to the greatest of all human quests: finding meaning in our lives.

But with that said, the re-appropriation of *atheism* is confusing at best and completely redefining it at worst. It would be best to stick to the original meaning, the first definition that you supplied, and if one finds oneself not quite fitting into the mold of one of the three then err on *agnosticism* when forced to use a single word and speak up to be heard when there is no such restriction. Even coin your one phrase if necessary; it might catch on.

Comment: I'm reminded of the word *skepticism*. That is an appropriate word for an *agnostic* who might believe if there was convincing evidence. Add on *scientific skepticism* and that would be appropriate for the apathetic position that some have toward all religion, because, in their mind, it cannot be scientifically supported.

Comment: Please comment if you choose to downvote and help me improve this answer.

Comment: "Atheism is a belief in not god." is not true

Comment: @Nanne You will have to give me more than that to convince me.

Comment: Seriously, downvotes do not help make posts better all by themselves. Comment with something substantial and let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Some uses of *atheist* in practice are:

1. Someone who does believe in any god.
2. Someone who believes that there is no god.
3. Someone who does not believe in the god that the speaker considers it self-evident to be the only god.
4. Someone who does not believe in an ultimate monotheistic creator-god, though they may believe in several other beings who are commonly also termed* *gods*.
5. Someone who believes that there is definitely not an ultimate monotheistic creator-god, though they may believe in several other beings who are commonly also termed *gods*.

Now, of those, (and I'm not claiming the above is exhaustive), there are differing opinions as to whether they are correct at all.

They may also depend on context; number 5 could cover both polytheists for whom their disbelief in an ultimate monotheistic creator-god is not a significant item of theology, but also those Buddhists who do believe in gods (not all Buddhists do) for whom the doctrine that there is no ultimate eternal being is an important doctrine. This might lead us to use *atheist* of such Buddhists, but not of other such polytheists for whom the belief is more incidental.

This is a bit of a nuisance when we're talking in detail about religious belief, or lack thereof, but not a great nuisance; in such cases we can simply define our terms.

The idea that we would be sure to find an answer to the question to "Which definition is the proper usage?" is untenable and contradictory.

We're talking about a language here in which we can't find a single definition by which to decide whether *berry* includes tomatoes or not. We have several definitions of *integer* within the field of mathematics alone. It's hardly surprising to find that there are overlapping definitions of a term relating to human belief.

For that matter, *agnostic* too has at least two common definitions:

1. Someone lacking belief in god(s) or belief in their being no god.
2. (As originally coined by Huxley) Someone who holds that **nobody** knows if there is a god or not.

And again, I'm not claiming to be exhaustive.

*"Commonly also termed" because by definition, if you are using *atheist* in this way you are focusing on the definition of *god* that expects an eternal, all-powerful being, which is rejected by some views (such as Buddhism) and of little interest to some others ("They quite realise that there must be some great 'Prime Mover', some Supreme Deity; but they think that if It gives them no means of knowing It, it is because It does not want to be known" - Gerard Gardner, though personally I disagree with the assumption suggested in "They quite realise that there must be"). As such, some may reject the use of *god* for those beings they do believe, while others my not (I personally fit the fourth definition above, but don't use it, and hence don't call myself an atheist). Really, it comes down to *god* having been defined in more than one way too, combined with the difficulty of translation the further afield one goes from the European, Middle Eastern and North African "known world" of the time it came to have the definitions it does have.

Comment: This list sounds unusual. It gives me the impression that it's created by a monotheist who uses _atheist_ as a slur. For instance, (4) is derogatory towards polytheists (whose gods are only _commonly termed_ gods) in addition to heaping polytheists and atheists together.

Comment: @MSalters no, it's inclusive of those who do not agree with the term *god* being used. Whether the Tuatha Dé Danann, or devas, for example should be considered *gods* or something different is something that not all those who believe in them agree on. Number 3 certainly is about monotheists who use *atheist* as a slur, but such people do exist, and so the word is definitely used that way.

Comment: It's definitely not the first usage that comes to mind, but fair enough.  It fits the definition well enough.  As to Agnostic having multiple meanings, I cannot buy that.  A-gnostic meaning not knowing.  It's pretty cut and dried. Otherwise, I have to accept the usage of literally to mean figuratively just because of common improper usage!  (Stupid dictionaries knuckling under!)

Comment: @DavidM "That it is wrong for a man to say he is certain of the objective truth of a proposition unless he can provide evidence which logically justifies that certainty. This is what agnosticism asserts and in my opinion, is all that is essential to agnosticism." - T H Huxley (coiner of the term *agnostic*).

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood me.  I agree with Huxley, not the usage of agnostic to mean atheist.  It's the opposite of the Gnostics.  For which I cannot find a reference that does not strictly refer to the Christian movement.  I know the concept of gnosticism through the Kabbalah, etc.

Comment: @DavidM ah, you object to the other definition of it as not committing to a view either way. I'm afraid it's quite definitely used that way.

Comment: @MSalters I've added a clarification, which you may or may not be content with.

Comment: @JonHanna Ah, I misunderstood.  I think the phrasing threw me off.   I probably would have phrased it as "Simultaneously lacking a belief in either the existence or absence of god(s)."  I would have caught onto that.

Comment: Wouldn't 4) be called a **theist** = *the belief that at least one deity exists*?

Answer (score 3):

*Atheism* and *atheist* are forgiving words. The speaker may be referring to

- *believing* in the *nonexistence* of a god, or
- *not believing* in (doubting) the *existence* of a god, which is different, or
- *estrangement* from or *disobedience* of a god which exists,

depending on context, including the speaker’s own beliefs. This is true, not just of usage in the modern era, but clear back to the 16th century when the words were first borrowed from French.

Being estranged from a god which exists was the original meaning. The term *atheist* wasn’t invented by atheists ; it was invented by religious believers as an epithet (a disparaging word). It literally means “without god”, and was used to characterize people who denied the gods or were estranged from the gods in some way. The religious still sometimes use it in this sense.

Atheists co-opted the word in the way that Americans co-opted the term *Yankee*. Subsequently, the meaning of the term mutated quite a bit, as people argued over time about the existence of a god and what you can know about it.

Some dictionary entries are so short that they lose the nuances of meaning of these words. Unabridged dictionaries and scholarly articles are better guides.

The best hope you have when you hear either term is that the person using it defines it in context. That is also the best thing to do when you use it yourself.

## Sources

[“atheism”, *A New English Dictionary On Historical Principles*, Vol 1, A and B](https://archive.org/stream/oed01arch#page/532/mode/2up). This work is in the public domain. As it is not an easily searchable source, I have transcribed the relevant entries in full :

> **Atheism** (ēⁱ·þ*i*ˌiz’m). Also **6 athisme**. [a. F. *athéisme* (16th c. in Littré), f. Gr. ἄθεος : see Aᴛʜᴇᴀʟ and -ɪꜱᴍ. Cf. It. *atheismo* and the earlier Aᴛʜᴇᴏɴɪꜱᴍ.]
> Disbelief in, or denial of, the existence of a God.
> *Also*, Disregard of duty to God, godlessness (*practical* atheism).
>
>     <sup>**1587** Gᴏʟᴅɪɴɢ *De Mornay* xx. 310 Athisme, that is to say, vtter godlesnes.
>
>     **1605** Bᴀᴄᴏɴ *Adv. Learn.* ɪ. i. § 3 A little or superficial knowledge of philosophy may incline the mind of man to atheism.
>
>     **1711** Aᴅᴅɪꜱᴏɴ *Spect.* No. 119 ⁋ 5 Hipocrisy in one Age is generally succeeded by Atheism in another.
>
>     **1859** Kɪɴɢꜱʟᴇʏ *Lett.* (1878) II. 75 Whatever doubt or doctrinal Atheism you and your friends may have, don’t fall into moral Atheism.</sup>
>
>
> **Atheist** (ēⁱ·þ*i*ˌist). Also **6 atheyst, 6–7 athist(e.** [a. F. *athéiste (16th c. in Littré), or It. *atheista* : see prec. and -ɪꜱᴛ.]
> **1**. One who denies or disbelieves the existence of a God.
>
>     <sup>[*a* **1568** Cᴏᴠᴇʀᴅᴀʟᴇ *Hope of Faithf.* Pref. Wks. II. 139 Eat we and drink we lustily ; to-morrow we shall die : which all the epicures protest openly, and the Italian *atheoi*.]
>
>     **1571** Gᴏʟᴅɪɴɢ *Calvin on Ps.* Ep. Ded. 3 The Atheistes which say .. there is no God.
>
>     **1604** Rᴏᴡʟᴀɴᴅꜱ *Looke to it* 23 Thou Damned Athist .. That doest deny his power which did create thee.
>
>     **1709** Sʜᴀꜰᴛᴇꜱʙ. *Charac.* ɪ. ɪ. § 2 (1737) II. ɪɪ To believe nothing of a designing Principle or Mind, nor any Cause, Measure, or Rule of Things, but Chance .. is to be a perfect Atheist.
>
>     **1876** Gʟᴀᴅꜱᴛᴏɴᴇ in *Contemp. Rev.* June 22 By the Atheist I understand the man who not only holds off, like the sceptic, from the affirmative, but who drives himself, or is driven, to the negative assertion in regard to the whole Unseen, or to the existence of God.</sup>
>
>
> **2**. One who practically denies the existence of a God by disregard of moral obligation to Him ; a godless man.
>
>     <sup>**1577** Hᴀɴᴍᴇʀ *Anc. Eccl. Hist.* 63 The opinion which they conceaue of you, to be Atheists, or godlesse men.
>
>     **1660** Sᴛᴀɴʟᴇʏ *Hist. Philos.* 323/2 An Atheist is taken two ways, for him who is an enemy to the Gods, and for him who believeth there are no Gods.
>
>     **1667** Mɪʟᴛᴏɴ *P. L.* ɪ. 495 When the Priest Turns Atheist, as did Ely’s Sons.
>
>     **1827** Hᴀʀᴇ *Guesses* Ser. ɪ. (1873) 27 Practically every man is an atheist, who lives without God in the world.</sup>
>
>
> **B.** *attrib.* as *adj.* Atheistic, impious.
>
>     <sup>**1667** Mɪʟᴛᴏɴ *P. L.* ᴠɪ. 370 The Atheist crew.
>
>     **1821** Lᴏᴄᴋʜᴀʀᴛ *Valerino* II. xi. 316 Borne from its wounded breast an atheist cry Hath pierced the upper and the nether sky.</sup>

[“atheism”, *The Catholic Encylopedia*](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/02040a.htm):

> Since its first coming into use the term atheism has been very vaguely employed, generally as an epithet of accusation against any system that called in question the popular gods of the day. Thus while Socrates was accused of atheism (Plato, Apol., 26, c.) and Diagoras called an atheist by Cicero (Nat. Deor., I, 23), Democritus and Epicurus were styled in the same sense impious (without respect for the gods) on account of their trend of their new atomistic philosophy. In this sense too, the early Christians were known to the pagans as atheists, because they denied the heathen gods ; while, from time to time, various religious and philosophical systems have, for similar reasons, been deemed atheistic. … Atheism, historically considered, has meant no more in the past than a critical or sceptical denial of the theology of those who have employed the term as one of reproach, and has consequently no one strict philosophical meaning.
>
> > For there are gods : for our knowledge of them is indistinct. But they are not of the character which people in general attribute to them.
> > —Lucretius Carus, Laert., Life of Epicurus, XXVII
>
> Indeed, this one citation perfectly illustrates the fundamental historic meaning of the term, atheism.

[“atheism”, *Concise Dictionary of Religion*, Irving Hexham, 1999](http://people.ucalgary.ca/%7Enurelweb/books/concise/WORDS-A.html):

> originally used in Greece of all those who, whether they believed in a god or not, disbelieved in the official gods of the State : Socrates was the classic instance. In the Roman Empire the term was applied to Christians but sometimes Christians, like Polycarp, would turn the term against their persecutors. Until the expression “agnosticism” came into general use in the nineteenth century, the term “atheism” was popularly used to describe those who thought the existence of God an unprovable thesis.

[“atheism”, *Free On-Line Dictionary of Philosophy* 3.0, 26-03-2001](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.105.181&rep=rep1&type=pdf):<sup>[PDF]</sup>

> the belief that, or the philosophical position according to which, God, gods, deities, and supernatural powers do not exist. In this respect it is similar to secularism and opposed to any variety of theism. … Popularly, atheism is often taken to imply a lack of any ideals or values whatsoever (see immoralism), but this connotation rests on the controversial assumption that religious or supernatural values are the only real values.

[“atheism”, *Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy*](http://www.iep.utm.edu/atheism/):

> negative atheism … includes someone who has never reflected on the question of whether or not God exists and has no opinion about the matter and someone who had thought about the matter a great deal and has concluded either that she has insufficient evidence to decide the question, or that the question cannot be resolved in principle. … Atheism can be narrow or wide in scope. The narrow atheist does not believe in the existence of God (an omni-being). A wide atheist does not believe that any gods exist, including but not limited to the traditional omni-God.

[“atheism”, *Philosophy Pages*, Garth Kemerling](http://www.philosophypages.com/dy/a9.htm#athe):

> Belief that god does not exist. Unlike the agnostic, who merely criticizes traditional arguments for the existence of a deity, the atheist must offer evidence (such as the problem of evil) that there is no god or propose a strong principle for denying what is not known to be true.

[“atheism”, *The Century Dictionary and Cyclopedia*](http://www.wordnik.com/words/atheism):

> n. The doctrine that there is no God ; denial of the existence of God.
> n. The denial of theism, that is, of the doctrine that the great first cause is a supreme, intelligent, righteous person.
> n. A practical indifference to and disregard of God ; godlessness.

[“atheism”, *Merriam-Webster Dictionary*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/atheism):

> 1 a : a lack of belief or a strong disbelief in the existence of a god or any gods
> 1 b : a philosophical or religious position characterized by disbelief in the existence of a god or any gods
> 2 *archaic* : godlessness especially in conduct : *ungodliness, wickedness*

[atheism, *Webster’s Revised Unabridged*, 1913 Edition](http://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/atheism):

> n. 1. The disbelief or denial of the existence of a God, or supreme intelligent Being.
> 2. Godlessness.

[“atheism”, *Webster’s New World College Dictionary*, 4th Edition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/atheism):

> • The belief that there is no God, or denial that God or gods exist.
> • Godlessness.

[atheism, *Dictionary.com*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/atheism):

> 1. the doctrine or belief that there is no God.
> 2. disbelief in the existence of a supreme being or beings.

[“atheism”, *Collins English Dictionary*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/atheism):

> • The belief that there is no God.
> • Rejection of belief in God or gods.

[“atheism”, *Webster’s Dictionary*, 1828](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/atheism):

> • The disbelief of the existence of a God, or Supreme intelligent Being.

[“atheism”, *Webster’s New World College Dictionary*](http://www.yourdictionary.com/atheism):

> • Disbelief in or denial of the existence of God or gods.

[“atheism”, *Macmillan Dictionary*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/atheism):

> • The belief or theory that God does not exist.

[“atheism”, *Oxford Learner’s Dictionaries*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/atheism):

> • The belief that God does not exist.

[“atheism”, *Cambridge Dictionary*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/atheism):

> • The belief that God does not exist.

Comment: +1 for "estrangement from or disobedience of a god which exists". A lot of people don't realize that historical perspectives on "belief in God" was more about physical acts of worship,  rather than intellectual acceptance of the religion as fact. Though, I would adjust the wording to "... of a god assumed to exist by the society or culture".

Answer (score 1):

The definitions are not competing, the first one clearly implies the second, while the second without the first is a specific form of atheism that could obviously only mean those naive and pure enough to not have been pestered to think about and commit to god, so that you wouldn't actually be in a place to know what they think, and hence couldn't label them.